# Android extendablelistveiw child element in foreground

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm not sure that extendable list is the best solution for this but this is the only thing that came to my mind.

Here is my problem:

I want to create a list and when I click on an element one (or maybe there'll be multiple) element'll appear and push down the other elements that are below it. This is how the extendable list works, but here comes my problem I want that the child element are in front of the group elements and I have no idea how could I do it.
Here it is a picture maybe you can understand it better:
[image]

As Gavriel requested:

main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.lalala.listview.MainActivity">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/extd_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_widthPercent="75%"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_text"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />


</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

expanded child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/extended_item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use a dialog view for showing you child list, it will automatically come over the main list as a popup

Comment: if I use dialog view it'll only show up overt the list, it won't push down the other elements @arshadkazmi42

Comment: Zoli, show us the layout xmls you have

Comment: it is nothing special, it is a basic expandablelistview with a custom adapter, the default version works great but the problem is I don't know how to do the thing I want so I think you won't see anything from the xml-s, but here they are @Gavriel

Answer (score 1):

What i did in a similar situation was to copy the ExpandableListView's layout xml into my project, and modify it according to my needs, and create MyExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView that uses my version of the layout and doesn't change anything else. I hope this helps.

Comment: I hoped it would be easier ,well at least I can go to a direction, thank you very much